# Want the navigating page on the same page

Tags: java, servlets

my ajax some how looks like this :
    function getXMLHttpRequest() {
      var xmlHttpReq = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {

```
      xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (exp1) {
      try {

        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (exp2) {
        xmlHttpReq = false;
      }
    }
  }
  return xmlHttpReq;
}

function makeRequest() {
  var xmlHttpRequest = getXMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest);
  xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://abc.com:8080/someservletServlet/", true);
  xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlHttpRequest.send(null);
}


function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {

    return function() {
    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {

          document.getElementById("xml").value = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
      } else {
        alert("HTTP error " + xmlHttpRequest.status + ": " + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
      }
    }
  };
}   but somehow the servlet is not bringing the response it should bring. can you help. what could be the possible error.
```

Comment: for that you need to use Ajax , as that will help you partially refreshing the page content

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the way to go.Because if you submit the request, page will refresh whether its same page or different.

If you still want to achieve it using without using ajax and refresh of page is fine with you then see   if you have this kind of code in your servlet which is causing to forward it to some other page

```
  String nextJSP = "nextPage.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: is it possible using some kind of java script....AJAX is something i have never worked before...and these kind of codes (requsetDispather etc) are not present in the servlet. i have verified....

Comment: Ajax is very simple. See ajax hello world using jquery. Jquery just simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load some data from some other URL you'll need to send an AJAX request (explain where to get data from) and handle the AJAX response (explain what to do with the fetched data). To provide for a browser-compatible solution you'd better use some well-known JS library. For example, you could use jQuery in which case your script could look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "servletURL",//servlet URL to post data to
    type: "POST",//request type, can be GET
    cache: false,//do not cache returned data
    data: {id : idOfData},//data to be sent to the server
    dataType: "xml"//type of data returned
}).done(function(data) {
    //do something with XML data returned from server
});
```

With this approach you need to call the above JS code, probably wrapped in a JS function, on some JS event, i.e. `click`, and handle response data, for example, by appending its contents to your text area.

Comment: hi,my ajax some how looks like this :